# Finding nodes with a particular weight in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ and given two integers $n$ and $k$, I want to find (if they exist) $n$ nodes such that the sum $S$ of all the edges incident to such $n$ nodes is smaller than $k$. Of course, if an edge has both extremes in the $n$ nodes, its contribution to $S$ must be taken into account just once.

How can we retrieve such $n$ nodes whose sum $S$ is smaller than $k$?

Comment: Seems like a min-cost flow approach should work somehow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). Often something like this works: create a vertex for each node, a vertex for each edge, connect them if they hit each other. Create a source that connects to all the "node" vertices, and a sink that connects to all the "edge" vertices. Set edge costs and capacities in some clever way and find a min-cost flow, which tells you the answer. ... But in this case I don't see how to do it.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187925/induced-h-from-g-with-given-threshold Here it is the original problem whose the above post was supposed being a subprocedure for the solution.

Comment: Book? What book? Why are you interested in this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you have stated is a variation of the Cheeger / isoperimetric
problem. It is helpful to analyze it by posing a corresponding integer programming problem. Let
$E\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ and $F\in\{-1,0,1\}^{m\times n}$ be the
undirected and directed incidence matrices of the graph respectively,
\begin{align*}
E(e,v) & =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{edge }e\text{ hits vertex }v\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},\\
F(e,v) & =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{edge }e\text{ starts at vertex }v\\
-1 & \text{edge }e\text{ ends at vertex }v\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
\end{align*}
and let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be the weight matrix,
$$
W(e,e)=\text{weight of edge }e.
$$
Then given the support vector of a vertex set, $x\in\{0,1\}^{n}$,
the weight of the corresponding edge set hit by the vertex set is
$\frac{1}{2}(\|WEx\|_{1}+\|WFx\|_{1})$. To see this, note that $\|WEx\|_{1}$
will give the total sum of the edges hit by $x$, but will double
count the interior edges, i.e. if $e=\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$, then selecting
$v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ will count the weight of $e$ twice. Conversely,
$\|WFx\|_{1}$ will only give the total sum of the boundary edges,
i.e. if $e=\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$, then selecting $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$
will not count the weight of $e$ at all.

Hence if the specified vertex set exists, it will be found by the
binary linear integer program,
$$
x_{opt}=\{\arg\min\,\|WEx\|_{1}+\|WFx\|_{1}:\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=n,x\in\{0,1\}^{n}\},
$$
and the $l_{1}$ norm can be converted into linear objective and constraints
using standard techniques. If the objective is less than $2k$, then $x_{opt}$ satisfies
the original constraints; if not, then it is the closest vertex set
to satisfying the constraints. For smaller graphs, we may directly solve the integer program using branch-and-cut as the algorithm, and for medium-sized graphs, we may augment branch-and-cut with a good search heuristic.

Next, to consider the issue of building an algorithm with a good asymptotic complexity, note that one way to see the problem is a MINIMAL RESTRICTED CUTSET (aka "MIN K-CUTSET") problem with the cost function $\|WFx\|_1$ and $\|x\|_1$ constraint, but "regularized" by the monotonic cost function $\|WEx\|_1$. Indeed, most of the difficulties of the problem comes from its relation to the cut problem. Fortunately, MIN K-CUTSET is also a fairly well-studied problem, due to its relation to the isoperimetric cut. It should be possible to adopt existing algorithms designed for the isoperimetric problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but your very interesting solution is too advanced for the actual purposes of the exercise. I tried to re-edit the question such way that maybe someone can come up with an easier solution for this particular instance of the problem you described in its generality.

Comment: @Sergey: If we have an edge $e_1 = {v_1,v_2}$, and we include both vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the vertex set, then would we count the weight of edge $e_1$ once or twice? My answer assumed the former. For the latter, the problem has an extremely trivial solution. EDIT: reread your description. It is indeed the former.

Comment: I confirm you that as for weights, each edge that hits a node in the solution set must be counted once.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187925/induced-h-from-g-with-given-threshold. Here it is the original problem whose the above post was supposed being a subprocedure for the solution.